# push url to other local page

Tags: jquery, json, post, get

So im making an webos app for my self.
I need to push a url/name to another page, then redirect and view the pushed url.

I need this to be done with JQuery.

This is what i've got.

```
    <div class="twitch-widget-gamelist" id="twitch-widget-gamelist">
         // IN HERE IS A LOST OF GAMES
    </div>
    <div class="twitch-widget-streamlist" id="twitch-widget-streamlist">
         // IN HERE IS A LOST OF STREAMERS. THESE ARE LOADED WITH JQUERY/JSON SEE BELOW
    </div>
```

This is the JQuery with JSON load

```
$(document).on("click", "#twitch-widget-gamelist a", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          var name = $(this).attr("name");

          $("#game-list-header").text(name);

          name = name.replace(/\s/g,"+");
          name = name.replace(/\:/g,"%3A");

          $("#twitch-widget-gamelist").empty();

          $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=' + name + '&limit=100',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(data) {

                    $.each(data.streams, function(index, value){

                        $("#twitch-widget-streamlist").append("<a href='#' name='" + value.channel.name + "' id='" + value._id + "'><img src='" + value.preview.medium + "'></a>");

                    })
                }
            });
        });
```

When one of these images/links are clicked it should redirect to `stream.html` and show the stream. In the `stream.htm`l i've got this so far:

```
<div class="right_panel_stream">
        <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.nightdev.com/hosted/obschat/?style=light&channel=sodapoppin&fade=false&bot_activity=false" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
```

I somehow need to push the stream-name(`value.channel.name`) to the `stream.html` so i can change "`sodapoppin`" with what ever image/link is clicked.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can pass parameters via `location.hash` when redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ruslanas Balčiūnas says. I could use `location.hash` to do this. It worked, and i was able to send a hashtag to the other page, and use the `location.hash` to get the hashtag, for the purpose needed.